# error while updating apps in ubuntu touch

Tags: 14.04, updates, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I'm trying to update my ubuntu touch apps from both phone and `phablet-shell`.

When I tried it from phone, here is the error shows.

[image: screen shot of updating error]

also tried by adding there `ppa`

```
ppa:phablet-team/ppa
ppa:ubuntu-touch-coreapps-drivers/daily
```

and running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

also tried

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

all commands executed well. still the apps are not updated. any other methord to update my apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only limited options available with the stable version. I tried the develop version and amazed! It is awesome. Gone so much further than stable version. Give a try by connecting your phone to pc and running this command.

```
ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel
```

you will be switched to the develop channel and I bet you will gonna surprised after reboot. Most of the error are fixed also. But remember, it is not stable. So expect the unexpected.